# replicate 2 Different Databases to 1 Database

Tags: mysql, replication

How Could we replicate 2 Different Databases to 1 Database.
both 2 databases in Master has same tables.

```
[Master]
Database-A
Database-B


[Slave]
DatabaseA-B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`--replicate-rewrite-db="olddb->newdb"`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-rewrite-db). In your case you'd have to use this option twice. But be aware, that this breaks when you do something like this on the master:

```
USE Database-A;
UPDATE Database-B.foo SET bar=baz;
```